# How to print the user's DN using python ldap3

Tags: ldap, python

I'm using the *ldap3* module under python 2.7 and doing a search on my directory. I can retrieve the user's `cn:` but how do I properly retrieve the *distinguishedName* (specifically `DN:` below)?

```
>>> conn.search (BASE_DN, '(&(uid=user456))', attributes=['*'])
True

>>> print conn.entries[0]
DN: uid=user456,ou=myou,dc=myorg
    cn: user456
...

>>> print conn.entries[0]['cn']
user456

>>> print conn.entries[0]['DN']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap3/abstract/entry.py", line 100, in __getitem__
    return self.__getattr__(item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap3/abstract/entry.py", line 88, in __getattr__
    raise LDAPKeyError('key not found')
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPKeyError: 'key not found'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results of a [python ldap3 search](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/searches.html#response) are not only attributes but  tuples  of the form **`(dn, attributess, raw_attributes)`**, where:

- **`dn`**: a string containing the DN (distinguished name) of the entry
- **`attributes`** : a dictionary of returned attributes and their values. Values are list. Values are in UTF-8 format
- **`raw_attributes`**: same as ‘attributes’ but not encoded (bytearray)

The DN itself is not an attribute (of the DN)...

Displaying the DN and CN therefore looks something like:

```python
conn.search (BASE_DN, '(&(uid=user456))', attributes=['*'])

for dn,attrs,raw_attrs in conn.search.response:
   print dn
   print attrs['cn']
```

Comment: Seemed like the answer was pretty clear but can't get it to work the way you show. `conn.search()` just returns `True`. That doesn't seem like a tuple. Should it maybe use `conn.entries` somehow instead of `my_search_results`?

Comment: I was about to close down for the day and not too sharp now either as I ‘d typically use python-ldap but maybe  it should be a loop over `conn.response`

Comment: Thanks. `print conn.response[0]['dn']` does it. Appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the DN from entries like this:

```
for entry in conn.entries:
    print(entry.entry_dn)
```